# custom accept function in start-server clojure

Tags: clojure, clojure-repl

I'm trying to run `clojure.core.server/start-server` but instead of using the repl I want a custom function as accept option. I'm following [this post](https://insideclojure.org/2020/09/30/exec-example/) where a repl server is executed as

```
clojure -X clojure.core.server/start-server :name '"server"' :port 5555 :accept clojure.core.server/repl :server-daemon false
```

What requirements do I need to pass a function to accept opt? What if I only want to print the request from any connection? Using something like `clojure.core/println` didn't work

```
clojure -X clojure.core.server/start-server :name '"server"' :port 5555 :accept clojure.core/println :server-daemon false
```

btw, I can't even run `start-server` on the repl itself, I've got the error everytime a made a request. Is it possible to run it from the repl?

```
(clojure.core.server/start-server {:name "server" :port 9000 :accept clojure.core.server/repl :server-daemon false})
#object[java.net.ServerSocket 0x25b865b5 "ServerSocket[addr=localhost/127.0.0.1,localport=9000]"]
user=> Exception in thread "Clojure Connection server 1" java.lang.ClassCastException: class clojure.core.server$repl cannot be cast to class clojure.lang.Named (clojure.core.server$repl and clojure.lang.Named are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
        at clojure.core$namespace.invokeStatic(core.clj:1612)
        at clojure.core.server$accept_connection.invokeStatic(server.clj:73)
        at clojure.core.server$start_server$fn__8998$fn__8999$fn__9001.invoke(server.clj:117)
        at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `start-server` function states, that `:accept` must be a *namespaced
**symbol*** (so this is the reason, why you see the error in your REPL
(you are passing a *variable*; use `'clojure.core/println` instead --
note the leading `'`).

As for passing your own function, it helps to take a look at the
function `clojure.core.server/accept-connection`, what is actually going
on.  So basically your `:accept` function gets called with `*in*`,
`*out*`, `*err*` redirected (and also a binding of `*session*` with some
book-keeping) and the `:args`.  So you want to read/write on
stdin/stdout in your function and parameterize with the given arguments.

E.g. create a file `src/so.clj` with the following content:

```clj
(ns so)

(defn accept
  [prefix]
  (loop []
    (println prefix (read-line))
    (recur)))
```

Then start the server from the same root:

```bash
clojure -X clojure.core.server/start-server :name '"server"' :port 5555 \
  :accept so/accept \
  :args '[">>>"]' \
  :server-daemon false
```

Note the `:accept` symbol (it's coming from the shell, so Clojure reads
that as a symbol) points to the namespace and the function within.  Make
sure, things match up with the class-path (`src` is a default source
path for the Clojure CLI).

Also note the passing of the `:args` represented as an EDN array.
Inside `accept-connection` the call to your function is then `(apply accept args)`, so you can assume regular arguments in your accept-fn.

Then test your server with e.g. `telnet`:

```
% telnet localhost 5555
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
hello
>>> hello
world
>>> world
```